# Symfony - Redis and Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony

I saved the user information into Redis and fetch them when add new articles.

```
$userEntity = new User(); 
$userEntity->setId($redis->hGet($key, 'id'));
$userEntity->setName($redis->hGet($key, 'name'));

$articleEntity = new Article();
$articleEntity->setAuthor($userEntity);

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($articleEntity);
$em->flush();
```

But I got the error which told me there was duplicated Entry for `User#id`.

User entity has existed in database, only I want to do is build association with the article that will be added to database.

Is there any better way to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Reference Proxy](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#reference-proxies) object.

Try with:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$userEntity = $em->getReference(User::class, $redis->hGet($key, 'id'));

$articleEntity = new Article();
$articleEntity->setAuthor($userEntity);

$em->persist($articleEntity);
$em->flush();
```

Please keep in mind that creating a proxy object doesn't validate if such entity (with given ID) exists in database, therefore you have to make sure about that on your own.